# Тест на javarush.net -застрял

Tags: java, объекты

Вроде все верно, но что-то не так. Задача на английском закоментирована в коде.

```
/* A Man and A Woman
1. Create public static classes Man and Woman within the class Solution.
2. Classes must have fields: name(String), age(int), address(String).
3. Create constructors to pass all the possible parameters to.
4. Use the constructor to create two objects of each class with all the data.
5. Display the objects in format [name + " " + age + " " + address].
*/

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create two object of every class here
        Man man1 = new Man("Victor", 38, "Naberejnaya");
        Man man2 = new Man("Andrey", 39, "Kishinau");

        Woman woman1 = new Woman("Lena", 30, "Moscow");
        Woman woman2 = new Woman("Maria", 34, "Briceni");

        //output them to screen here
        System.out.println(man1.man);
        System.out.println(man2.man);

        System.out.println(woman1.woman);
        System.out.println(woman2.woman);
    }

    //add your classes here

    //CLASS MAN
    public static class Man {
        String man;
        String name;
        String address;
        int age;

        public Man(String name) { }

        public Man(int age) { }

        public Man(String name, String address) { }

        public Man(String name, int age) { }

        public Man(String name, int age, String address) {
            this.man = name + " " + age + " " + address;
        }
    }

    //CLASS WOMAN
    public static class Woman {
        String woman;
        String name;
        String address;
        int age;

        public Woman(String name) { }

        public Woman(int age) { }

        public Woman(String name, String address) { }

        public Woman(String name, int age) { }

        public Woman(String name, int age, String address) {
            this.woman = name + " " + age + " " + address;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Что у вас собственно не получается?

Comment: Как минимум, это условие нарушено в решении: " 2. Classes must have fields: name(String), age(int), address(String)."

Comment: И такой вопрос - зачем писать "this" в конструкторе, если такая переменная в параметрах конструктора отсутствует?

Comment: судя из условия параметры man и woman  не нужны. Сделайте один конструктор для всех параметров и инициализируйте их. thisперед названием параметра надо если имя параметра класса и входного параметра в конструктор совпадают, чтобы можно было их различить.

Comment: Переопределите метод toString() в котором возвращайте name + " " + age + " " + address

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Man {

    String name;
    String address;
    int age;

    Man(String name, int age, String address){

        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;
    }

   public void print() {
       System.out.println(name + " " + age + " " + address);
    }
}


public class Woman {


    String name;
    String address;
    int age;

    Woman(String name, int age, String address){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.address = address;

    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(name + " " + age + " " + address);
    }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {

        woman1.print();
        woman2.print();
    }
```